# Docusign Rest API vs the Saleforce toolkit

Tags: rest, salesforce, docusignapi

We would like to integrate Docusign internally with a Salesforce app. We would like to understand the pros and cons of using Docusign Toolkit for Salesforce vs using the Docusign Rest API directly for integration purpose. What are the limitations of the toolkit? Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Using DocuSign Apex Toolkit for Salesforce is highly recommended when invoking DocuSign eSignature REST API for automation around DocuSign Processes using Apex in the Salesforce organization. However, if the automation that is being developed uses a DocuSign REST API method that is not supported by any of the existing Apex Toolkit methods provided in the reference here https://developers.docusign.com/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/index.html then the customer may want to build their own custom integration to support their customized needs.
Using the Apex toolkit makes it much easier for us to setup the initial user Authorization and user consent that is required for accessing the DocuSign eSignature REST API's. We also do not have to create and maintain a separate DocuSign connected app since the toolkit internally uses the connected app used by the managed package.

Comment: Thanks @Inbar for the response. The toolkit is our first choice, but at the same time we do not want to have dependency on Docusign toolkit for the clients not wanting to use Docusign. Otherwise everyone will first need to install the toolkit which is not ideal.This is not DS issue. We will see if Salesforce provides calling apex classes dynamically.

Comment: Let me know if you need additional help. If the answer is satisfactory - please mark the question as answered.